# EE Spatial Join-- Generate columns in primary collection

Tags: google-earth-engine, spatial-join, feature-collection

I have two feature collections- a feature collection of different polygons (primary collection) and a .csv with various location data (secondary collection). I would like to append each column in the secondary collection to the each feature in the primary collection.

As it is now, I have a list of features (columns in secondary collection) appended to each feature in the primary collection, but when I export the data to a csv, all that shows up is a column with `<Feature>` in each column.

Here is my "secondary" feature collection. I would like to have these columns in the output csv:

[image: Here is my secondary feature collection]

Here is a snippet of the output CSV. See that "points" is the name of the secondary feature collection, and information such as Species, and No_Fish is lost.

[image: Here is my output CSV]

Here is my pseudo-code solution, extracting properties from an already joined feature collection:

```
for feature in joined:

    feat_points = feature.get("Points")

    //Iterate over each point in secondary collection that has been joined
    for point in feat_points:

        //Set each property name in secondary collection to primary collection
        for property in point: 
            feature.set("Property_name",property)
```

Here is a link to my code:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/a3ff4b90ac87ccc9199ad4861a9d4f54

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'Points' property is a list of features which pass the geo-join. You will need to map over the joined collection to get each of the secondary features'properties. I assume you would like to keep all properties from the primary feature, and append the properties of the secondary which pass the geo-join? You could do that as follows:

```
// add the properties of each feature secondary feature to each primary
var feats = studyHUCs.map(function(primary){
  var secondaries = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List(primary.get('Points')));
  // append primary properties
  return secondaries.map(function(secondary){
    return secondary.set(primary.toDictionary().remove(['Points']));
  });
}).flatten();
print(feats);
```

[link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/f607ba522169b30b77186ce548c29a7c)

Comment: That's correct, I would like to append the properties of secondary which pass the geo-join. However, each feature in the primary may have multiple secondaries which pass. A cursory glance indicates that ```feats``` only ever has 1 secondary appended. How would you recommend I keep information from each different secondary within the studyHUCs boundaries?

Comment: I think that does do it? [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/8cab36d4cb6a2b6ba0eeb9d8b24c5237). I think you deleted or renamed the asset, so I cannot check